# NodeJS: Determine whether a website supports SSL based on a url without protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I am using NodeJS with Express.

I have a form in which a customer can add their website url, so that I can make requests to their website API.

The problem is that the customer can add their url without the protocol e.g: `mywebsite.com`.

How can I determine if their website supports SSL? I need this in order to know if I should use the `http` or `https` module in NodeJS.

Comment: Try accessing https, fallback to http?

Comment: @ceejayoz You are correct. I can do that, but I was looking for a more 'elegant' solution.

Comment: You're going to have to reach out to the server in some way. Might as well be this way, as the other approaches could give you false positives (like you could check port 443, but that doesn't mean `example.com` is the domain on that port).

Answer (score 3):

Use an http request to the port 443. If it connects, https, otherwise http. It is not a silver bullet though as the server might have changed the https port.

However, the majority of the servers with https would reroute you to the https from the http, so just use the http codes (redirect) and follow them (google does that for example).